# What is the easiest way to check whether a function in two variables is continous?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

For functions like

$$f(x,y)=\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^2}$$ for $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$

and $$f(0,0)=0$$

it is tricky to verify whether it is continous at $(0,0)$ because the limit can depend on the way, $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ and might therfeore not exist. In the case above, it should help to use polar-coordinates (Is this correct ?)

But what can I do , if I have a function like

$$f(x,y)=\frac{\sin(x)\sin(y)}{x^2+y^2}$$

for $(x,y)\ne 0$ and $f(0,0)=0$ ?

> Is there an easy general method to verify continuity ?

Comment: No, there is no general method.

Comment: In this case, it helps to use the approximation $\sin(x) \sim x$ for small $x$.

Comment: This would lead to $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$, which is not continous, right ?

Comment: your first one is continuous, because if you write it in polar coordinates, it is bounded by a constant times $r.$

Comment: and your second one is discontinuous.

Comment: @DonAntonio Are there really hard cases ? Or does only no method exists which works in every case ?

Comment: A quick way to prove something is discontinuous is to substitute $y = kx$ and if the limit of $f(x,kx)$ is not constant, $f(x,y)$ is not continuous.  This is does not prove continuity, though.  Because there still may be a point in the neighborhood of $(0,0)$ which returns a different value of $f(x,y)$ and you need to be able to show that it is constant for every $x,y$ in the neighborhood.

Comment: Peter, this one is not genuinely difficult either: $x y^2 / (x^2 + y^4)$ at the origin, but the methods mentioned so far do not allow a definitive answer. A little more work is needed.